# Fatal error when trying to read JSON data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My code is

```
  let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSArray
                            let json = JSON(jsonData)


for (_, subJSON): (String, JSON) in json[0]["events"] {

 let rel1 = InboxEvents(title: subJSON["title"].string!, guests: subJSON["guests"].string!, eventpic: subJSON["eventpic"].string!, eventID : NSInteger(subJSON["ID"].string!)!)


self.arrayOfRels.append(rel1)

    }
```

Here is the `InboxEvents` class

```
class InboxEvents {

    var title = ""
    var guests = ""
    var eventpic = ""
    var eventID = 6


    init(title : String, guests: String, eventpic : String, eventID : NSInteger) {

        self.title = title
        self.guests = guests
        self.eventpic = eventpic
        self.eventID = eventID

    }
```

I am having `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in for loop.

json output is here

```
[
  {
    "events" : [
      {
        "ID" : "3",
        "title" : "Test Event",
        "guests" : 3,
        "eventpic" : "/images\/event_pic\/event1.jpg"
      },
      {
        "ID" : "1",
        "title" : "Test Event",
        "guests" : 2,
        "eventpic" : "/images\/event_pic\/event1.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What is the problem here ?

Comment: what is JSON in this code JSON(jsonData), did you have created a method or you are using and 3rd party

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the `subJSON["guests"]` in the json you have shown as the example the guest parameters is of Int type, but when you are fetching the value you are fetching the value as string
So when you simply print that value it will display nil and when you are trying to force unwrap it is crashing

So there can be two option

- Either you change your json guest property as string as in the InboxEvent you are passing as string
- Another option is you get the value in the interger/dobule according to your requirement convert it in to string and pass the in the InboxEvent or make InboxEvent take Int instead of string

Comment: hey i recently realized that, fixing now